# Add localStorage to this Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, thread-local-storage, angular-local-storage

Can you please help me add localStorage thing to the code below. I'm not good at creating Javascript code and still learning about it. The code is located below.

Comment: I don't see your code. Did you add it?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example:

You want to save in local storage the lastname of a person

you will do something like that:

Save in localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Wave");
```

With the above code, you do something like that `lastname = wave`

Get the value from localStorage

```
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

It will return `Wave`

Please be more specific about the data you want to save in localStorage from your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72631047/7992748)